# How can I install dependencies with composer if I have multiple composer.json in multiple directories?

Tags: php, command, composer-php

For example, let us say that we have something like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── module1
│   │   └── composer.json
│   └── module2
│       └── composer.json
└── composer.json
```

In every `composer.json` we have different dependencies.

How can I install all needed packages with a single command?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can create a `Makefile` that combines the necessary steps.

Nonetheless, you can install dependencies for all of the `composer.json` files by specifying the path to the working directories (the directories containing these `composer.json` files) using the `--working-dir` option.

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global-options:

> **--working-dir (-d)**: If specified, use the given directory as working directory.

#### `Makefile`

Here's an example:

```
.PHONY: composer

composer:
    composer install --working-dir app/module/1
    composer install --working-dir app/module/2
    composer install
```

and then run

```
$ make composer
```

Alternatively, have a look at [`beberlei/fiddler`](https://github.com/beberlei/fiddler) and see [Monolithic Repositories with PHP and Composer](http://www.whitewashing.de/2015/04/11/monolithic_repositories_with_php_and_composer.html) by Benjamin Eberlei.

Comment: hello what's .PHONY for ?

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html!

Answer (score 0):

Since ~2016 **you can use [composer local packages](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/02/07/how-to-decouple-monolith-like-a-boss-with-composer-local-packages/)**, that have native support.

To your example, just edit `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "path", "url": "app/module1" },
        { "type": "path", "url": "app/module2" }
    ]
}
```

And run:

```
composer update
```

That's all :)

Comment: This allows to install packages which *exist* locally, but as far as I understand, the original poster wanted to know how to install/update dependencies for multiple `composer.json` files within a single project.